# Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of collection

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to loop through server's response and I keep getting the following error:

> ```
> Type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' is a recursive collection data contract which is not supported. Consider modifying the definition of collection 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken' to remove references to itself.
> ```

Below is my code:

```
                    string url = $"***";
                    tracingService.Trace(url);
                    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
                    request.Method = "GET";
                    NetworkCredential myNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential("***@***.**", "***");
                    request.Credentials = myNetworkCredential;
                    request.ContentType = "application/json";

                    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                    if (response.StatusDescription == "OK")
                    {
                        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        tracingService.Trace(responseFromServer);

                        dynamic data = JObject.Parse(responseFromServer);

                        Entity history = new Entity("zst_casehistory");

                        //dynamic data1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);

                        foreach (var item in data.value)
                        {
                            tracingService.Trace("{0} {1} {2} {3}\n", item.No, item.Type, item.Barcode, item.PostingDate);
                            history["zst_servicereceiptno"] = item.No;
                            service.Create(history);
                        }
                    }
```

Can I avoid using Newtonsoft? Any help woulb be appreciated.

**EDIT:**

I still get the same error even though I modified the code like this:

```
                        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        tracingService.Trace(responseFromServer);

                        Entity history = new Entity("zst_casehistory");

                        var obj = JObject.Parse(responseFromServer);

                        var items = obj["value"];

                        foreach (var item in items)
                        {
                            tracingService.Trace(item["No"].ToString());
                            history["zst_servicereceiptno"] = item["No"];
                            service.Create(history);
                        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `dynamic` use `JToken` or `JArray`

You will be able to iterate over values and properties.

Comment: If I use JToken how can I access data.value?

Comment: Can you add here an example of the JSON you work with?